# C# - How to handle picturebox from datagridview if database record is null

Tags: c#

I am trying to get images from my datagridview and got success, but if some records dont have image or (null), than i got error ( Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]'.). Following is my code:

```
 private void dgridEmployees_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewCell cell = null;
        foreach (DataGridViewCell selectedCell in dgridEmployees.SelectedCells)
        {
            cell = selectedCell;
            break;

        }

        if (cell != null)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = cell.OwningRow;
            lbl_ID.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            tboxEmployeeID.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            tboxEmployeeName.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            dtboxJoiningDate.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            tboxDepartment.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            tboxPath.Text = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();

            byte[] img = (byte[])dgridEmployees.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value;
            if (img == null)
                pictureBox1.Image = null;
            else
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            }


        }
```

Please suggest any solution for my above code?

Comment: You should check with System.DBNull.Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to check if the cell contains no value. In this case, it's value will be `DBNull.Value` (the single instance of the `DBNull` class). You can only convert its value to a `byte[]` if the comparison is false.

```
if (dgridEmployees.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value != DBNull.Value)
{
    byte[] img = (byte[])dgridEmployees.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value;
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
else
{
    pictureBox1.Image = null;
}
```